# Send post data like curl

Tags: javascript, html, curl, boost-asio

I use this curl command to push a file to a web server

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @./mylocalfile -k https://192.168.1.10:8283/here
```

I want use a simple webpage instead where I can select the mylocalfile and I have this

```
<html>
<body>
    <input class="file" type="file" id="fafafa" name="fileupload" /><br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="xhrSubmit();" />
    <script type="text/javascript ">
        function xhrSubmit() {
            var file_obj = document.getElementById('fafafa').files[0];
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('fafafa', file_obj);
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'https://192.168.1.10:8283/here', true)
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            xhr.send(fd);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(obj);
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I use the webpage the webserver I get the response that it expected object or array.

How can I change the javascript code to send the data like the curl command that has no problems posting the file to the webserver?

The full boost exception from my server side is

```
Exception <unspecified file>(1): expected object or array
```

Comment: What is your server-side code?

Comment: It is my own developed code built on top of boost in C++. It works well for wget and curl commands both download and upload but I want try to use a webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem with this was that there where a lot of newlines in the json payload message and curl didn't care but the browser did.

Answer (score 1):

Your content-type is wrong. You are not sending JSON to your server.

Try setting content-type to *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*.

Comment: DId not change anything to use this content-type

Comment: I believe you should try and read about fundamentals of HTTP headers and XHR in general. It seams that you are randomly trying to make things work and that is not the way to go, ever :-).

Answer (score 0):

I would say, check what you received with the curl version. It can't be application/json and file data. You need multipart/form-data.

Comment: In curl I just found out I can write anything in content-type and it still works